# is it possible for a client esp8266 to control the esp8266 that set as an access point?

Tags: esp8266, remote-control

Im creating a project where i need to set one of my esp as a hotspot or access point but i would like to put a function where i could control the connected esp8266 client using the esp8266 that set as access point. I wonder if could use the acces point as a remote to control the client. Thank you in advance.

Comment: on the TCP/IP level they are peers